# Redshift - calculate the distance between two geometry points in different tables and pick the one with smallest distance

Tags: sql, geolocation, amazon-redshift, cartesian-product

Problem statement:

Redshift database

Two tables

```
- table_1 is over 1bn records
- table_2 is +-200k records
```

Both tables have columns of geometry type obtained by ST_MakePoint(lat,long).
The lat/longs represent locations:

```
table_1 - location of user
table_2 - location of postcode (central point of postcode)
```

I need to bring postcode from table_2 into table_1 based on the following criteria:

- the distance between the geopoints needs to be < (less than) 10km
- the postcode that has the smallest distance to the user's geopoint.

I am doing a Cartesian join and its just failing and I am wondering if someone might have a bright idea on how to query these two tables as I am not able to write anything that actually works.  This is what  I have at the moment:

```
with 
origin as 
(select distinct userid, latitude, longitude from table_1),
postcode AS 
(select postcode, postcode_sector, latitude, longitude from table_2),
cartesian as
(select userid
        ,o.latitude
        ,o.longitude
        ,postcode
        ,postcode_sector
        ,ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(o.latitude,o.longitude),ST_MakePoint(p.latitude,p.longitude))/1000 as distance
       , MIN(ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(o.latitude,o.longitude),ST_MakePoint(p.latitude,p.longitude))/1000) over (partition by o.userid,o.latitude ) as min_distance
  from origin o
  join postcode p on 1 =1 
  where (ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(o.latitude,o.longitude),ST_MakePoint(p.latitude,p.longitude))/1000) < 10  ) 

select a.*, b.postcode, b.postcode_sector
from public.table_1 a
left join cartesian b on  a.userid = b.userid and a.latitude = b.latitude
where  distance= min_distance
```

Is there some option for a left join considering the selection criteria?  Essentially, when one gives the criteria of < 10 km, multiple postcodes match, and out of that subset, I need to take the one with the smallest distance from the postcode center.

Please help!

Comment: Is it possible for you to break it down into two steps? Creating a persistent table from the calculation of distance and then doing the second operation?

Comment: Thanks Yankee, I am doing that split now. It has not been a success, still waiting for the query to complete.  I have also split out all the unecessary columns (less memeory needed) - I will add them on the left join (part 2).  Is it also the case that you dont see another way besides the cartesian product?